# Show PHP (v 7.0) code in browser in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, apache2, php

I install Ubuntu server 16.04 in VPS, after install I need to install PHP and Apache.

For PHP 7.0:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0
```

For Apache:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

But after install, in browser PHP codes show.

Do I need to change the apache2 setup to allow php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems according to [this](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-apache-with-php-and-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04-lamp/) that you need to install php7 apache-module

```
sudo apt-get -y install php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

Then restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Or

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```